# Python ctypes: Passed arguments are null when using restype

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to use a C library (libmms, although that's not really important) with `ctypes`; I wrote a small working C program first, but I seem to be having difficulty getting it to work with `ctypes`

Whenever I specify the return type (which is required, for I need it later) using `test.restype = custom_t` things start to break.

My arguments (`url` in specific) don't seem to work, or work very strangely (see the comments in C file). If I reduce the struct to just one entry (`int a`) everything works as expected! (It breaks at about 3 or 4 lines, the original struct from libmms is much larger).

I've (obviously) tried adding `argtypes`, muck about with various datatypes, etc., all to no avail...

Some simple example code to demonstrated the problem:

C library:

```
// Compiled with: clang -shared -Wl,-soname,test -o test.so -fPIC test.c
// Also tried gcc, with the same results
#include <stdio.h>

struct mmsh_t {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
};

// Called as: test(None, None, b'Hello', 42)
// Outputs: mmsh_connect: (null)
struct mmsh_t *mmsh_connect (void *io, void *data, const char *url, int bandwidth) {

// Called as: test(42, b'Hello')
// Segfaults
// Curiously, when I output this with the Python code:
// test(b'Hello')
// It outputs:  mmsh_connect: Hello
// Which is what I expected!
//struct mmsh_t *mmsh_connect (int io, const char *url) {

// Called as: test(b'Hello')
// Outputs: mmsh_connect: 
//struct mmsh_t *mmsh_connect (const char *url) {
    struct mmsh_t *this;
    printf("mmsh_connect: %s\n", url);
    return this;
}
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Python2 give the same results

import ctypes

class custom_t(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('a', ctypes.c_int),
        ('b', ctypes.c_int),
        ('c', ctypes.c_int),
        ('d', ctypes.c_int),
        ('e', ctypes.c_int),
    ]

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.so');
test = lib.mmsh_connect
test.restype = custom_t # <- Oh woe is this line!

test(None, None, b'Hello', 42)
#test(42, b'Hello')
#test(b'Hello')
```

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returns a pointer to a structure, not a structure.

```
test.restype = ctypes.POINTER(custom_t)
```

Also you need to declare the arguments to the function:

```
lib.mmsh_connect.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_char_p, c_int]
```

Usage:

```
s = lib.mmsh_connect(None, None, 'Hello', 42)
print ctypes.c_value(s.contents.a)
```

Comment: @eryksun Indeed. I've added a usage example from memory, please rectify if I got it wrong.

Comment: `ctypes.c_value` doesn't exist. `s[0].a` (or `s.contents.a`) returns a Python integer. Sometimes you need to use the `value` attribute of a simple type (e.g. if it's passed by reference as an out parameter), but as a result or struct field, ctypes does automatic conversion of simple types.

Comment: I don't need to declare the arguments, it seems to work fine without. The key was in using `restype = ctypes.POINTER(custom_t)`. Thanks!

Comment: In this case they're always NULL; I'm not even sure what they do (no docs), I looked up an app that uses this lib, which also sets them to NULL... But yeah, I get your point. Thanks for the explanation :)